# Windows will not accept keystrokes

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have a Windows 10 laptop (a Lenovo ThinkPad T490) that will not recognize any keystrokes from the keyboard, not even Function keys.

Here's what *works*:

- On-screen keyboard
- Keyboard controls in BIOS
- Laptop shortcut keys, like brightness controls and WiFi/Bluetooth toggles

Here's what *doesn't* work:

- Rebooting the machine ("have you tried turning it off and back on?")
- Updating PS/2 Keyboard driver
- Uninstalling PS/2 Keyboard driver & rebooting
- Filter Keys (already disabled)
- An external keyboard

Since it works fine in the BIOS, and a USB keyboard isn't any better, I know it isn't a hardware problem.  It almost seems like keystrokes have been disabled in the operating system.  This machine is used by the general public, so I can't necessarily rule out a malicious user (although our antivirus hasn't picked up anything).

What else can I can try?

Comment: Have you checked if Lenovo Quick Clean is in the Startup Folder? See p. 15 of the T490 User Guide.

Comment: Sounds like malware to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  It wasn't the operating system or drivers, it was the SiteKiosk software that's installed on this machine.  Apparently keyboard lock is a [feature](http://sitekiosk.com/CustomerSupportCenter/ArticleDetails.aspx?ArticleID=322) that can [turn itself on.](https://www.provisio.com/CustomerSupportCenter/ArticleDetails.aspx?ArticleID=21877)